# How to search the file contents in multiple subversion repositories?

Tags: regex, svn, version-control, search

I've got multiple SVN repositories of different projects which I would like to search for the same search term / regex, but without checking out or updating each project and doing the search manually on each of them.

**I'd like to know if it is possible to search the file contents in multiple SVN repositories for some search term (or regex).**

Comment: Are you trying to search within the files, or just the filenames?

Comment: I want to search the file content, so yes, within the file.

Comment: It sounds like you would do best to work directly on the repository's filesystem.  If you're only looking in specific files, there's `svn cat`, but if you want a recursive directory search... I have no idea.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a script:

```
if [[ $# < 2 ]]; then
    echo "Usage: $0 REGEX TARGET..."
    echo "where REGEX is a regular expression for grep"
    echo "and TARGET... is a list of SVN repositories"
    exit
fi

regex=$1
shift

for svnroot in $@; do
    for path in $(svn ls --recursive $svnroot); do
        if [[ $path != */ ]]; then
            svn cat $svnroot/$path \
                | grep --label="$svnroot/$path" --with-filename $regex 
        fi
    done
done
```

Comment: What language is this? Is it a bash script?